# Exporting data from Access to existing SQL Server DB tables?

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access

I have created a DB with empty tables in SQL Server, and created the relationship between all of those tables. 
A DB in Access with different kinds of tables (compared to the ones in SQL Server) holds a lot of data. I want to be able to insert the data existing in Access to my tables in SQL Server.

Since the tables in the Access DB and SQL Server DB is nowhere near alike, I can't just using an import/export wizard directly. Should I let the wizard create a new table in SQL Server, and use `INSERT INTO`, to move the data from this temporary table to my actual tables? Is there an easier method to do this?

Also, when exporting data from one DB to another, how do I make sure to keep information together? For example, in the Access DB there is mainly one big table with all information about the products, including suppliers. I wanted to make this more normalized in SQL Server, creating a table for product information, and a table for suppliers - to combine this information, I made a third table with a FK to suppliers, and a FK to products, and information regarding those two together.

Is there a clever way to insert the correct product ID and the correct supplier ID in this third table when exporting data?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: 1) Link SQL Server tables into Access, 2) create "clever" INSERT queries in Access - FROM Access tables, INTO linked tables.

Comment: Or generate a CSV and match column names to SQL Server then do an import || Completely duplicate the table layout in SQL server and directly import any generated CSVs and then create the views you need for better data layout?

Comment: FYI: SQL is an industry language that even Access runs. It is not an abbreviation for SQL Server.

Comment: There is no clever way besides what you build. Personally I would feel better migrating the data as-is from your Access database into your SQL server (into a new set of tables) and then working in SQL server to populate your new schema from those tables. Take it slow and make sure you think through each step. There is no "Auto-normalize my schlock data into this much nicer schema I came up with" button, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I've come to the decision that I'll have to migrate the whole Access DB into an SQL Server DB, and from there query the data from the temporary tables into my premade SQL Server tables, as @JNevill writes.

Comment: Much better idea @loragi. It also gives you far better traceability. For example if something is missing at the end then you can check if it existed when the data was imported or not by looking at your load tables.